# What are the FOSS solutions for partition merging?

Tags: hardware, partitioning, hard-drive

What are the FOSS solutions for partition merging in Ubuntu?

Comment: Gparted, though you shouldn't do anything when the filesystems are mounted

Comment: "Partition merging"? Like, making one partition with all the files on it from two partitions that each have their own files? I don't think there is a way to do this.

Comment: there are some commercial software that gives this feature. GPart had it, but i was looking for something different.

Answer (score 1):

Don't merge, Use MD to create a `linear` volume to simply concatenate the two partitions. This assumes you've backed up all the data on those partitions, wiped them out, marked them as `fs type fd`, and delegated them to `mdadm`. Partition Magic can probably perform the merge too and has support for ext filesystems.

Comment: I might sound stupid but what is `MD` and what is `linear volume`?

Comment: It's not a stupid question :). It's the dominant software RAID solution for Linux. Linear is a RAID level which simply concatenates devices together, it provides no fault tolerance. However it is handy for situations such as yours where a disk as several partitions, re-partitioning isn't an option, and you want to make the most of the free space.

Comment: Another option would be to create an LVM Volume Group that consists of the two partitions. Then you could create a logical volume from that *pool* of devices you gave it. In retrospect, that's probably the easier of the two to implement. http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/410